# How do I get all triggers from Google Tag Manager API with PHP SDK?

Tags: php, sdk, google-tag-manager, google-api-php-client

I want to get all Google Tag Manager-Triggers from the given SDK. So first I created the Google_client object, setting authentification, setting scopes and creating the Google_Service_TagManager Object.

Lines are:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/serviceaccount.json';
$client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
$client->setScopes([
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.edit.containers',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.delete.containers',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.edit.containerversions',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.publish',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.manage.users',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.manage.accounts'
        ]);

$tagmanagerService = new Google_Service_TagManager($client);
```

I have the following code for getting all the triggers:

```
$triggers = $tagmanagerService->triggers->listAccountsContainersWorkspacesTriggers('accounts/__ACCOUNT_ID__/containers/__CONTAINER_ID__/workspaces/__WORKSPACE_ID__);
```

But when I want to see whats in variable $triggers, there are these exceptions:

- Notice: Undefined property: Google_Service_TagManager::$triggers
  AND
- Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function listAccountsContainersWorkspacesTriggers() on null

Getting an account works fine with this line of code:

```
$account = $tagmanagerService->accounts->get('accounts/xyz');
```

What am I doing wrong? Above the listAccountsContainersWorkspacesTriggers-Method in the documentation there they write, that triggers should be initalized like that:

```
$tagmanagerService = new Google_Service_TagManager(...);
$triggers = $tagmanagerService->triggers;
```

And the parameter $path for this method is in Format `

> `accounts/{account_id}/containers/{container_id}/workspaces/{workspace_id}`

as I have.

Can you help me?